# Rails User or Group Pages Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, static-pages

I'm looking for a rails gem that allows my users (and or groups) the ability to create "pages".

I want it similar (if not nearly exactly) like pages.github.com, which I believe uses a library called Jekyll.

I've looked into this briefly, but I haven't been able to find any more... complete solutions.

Does anyone know of a solution that does what I'm looking for? I'd like to configure it for my models Group and User.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't about Jekyll, but his website says "is a blog-aware, static site generator in Ruby", and I don't think that's the case.

A solution is to store the pages created by the users to the Database, you can use Textile and/or RedCloth (instead of pure HTML).

There is a nice railscast how to create semi-static pages, I am sure you can get some good ideas: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just roll my own with RedCloth, shouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the listed Gems
Devise + CanCan + Rolify

Use Devies to authenticate your users.
Use CanCan to authorize your users Roles.
Use Rolify to create the roles on your users that cancan checks.

Then just make a generic page model where the ability checks the roles to see if a user can read, update, create or destroy.